# Change GameObject at main thread from an Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, interface, listener

I would like somehow to change a GameObject from a async Thread. I need to keep the listener/interface architecture.

Below I've created a simple example of my current implementation.

Main script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour, IMyComponentListener
{
    public GameObject cube;

    private MyComponent _myComponent;

    private void Start()
    {
        _myComponent = new MyComponent(this);
    }

    public void OnThreadCompleted()
    {
        cube.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 10f);
    }
}
```

Thread Script:

```
using System.Threading;

public class MyComponent
{
    private readonly IMyComponentListener _listener;

    public MyComponent(IMyComponentListener listener)
    {
        _listener = listener;

        Thread myThread = new Thread(Run);

        myThread.Start();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        _listener.OnThreadCompleted();
    }
}
```

Listener interface:

```
public interface IMyComponentListener
{
    void OnThreadCompleted();
}
```

If I try this code I will face the following error:

```
get_transform can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.
UnityEngine.GameObject:get_transform()
MyScript:OnThreadCompleted() (at Assets/Scripts/MyScript.cs:18)
MyComponent:Run() (at Assets/Scripts/MyComponent.cs:20)
```

Is clear I can't change main thread elements from a async Thread, but how do I workaround it or properly implement a architecture who supports this?

Comment: Maybe [coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) will solve your problem. If not you can take a look at shiny, new [job system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystem.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured a workaround using a external component [UnityMainThreadDispatcher](https://github.com/PimDeWitte/UnityMainThreadDispatcher).

After follow the [installation instructions](https://github.com/PimDeWitte/UnityMainThreadDispatcher#installation) I've updated my dispatcher to the example below and worked as charm!

Thread script:

```
using System.Threading;

public class MyComponent
{
    private readonly IMyComponentListener _listener;

    public MyComponent(IMyComponentListener listener)
    {
        _listener = listener;

        Thread myThread = new Thread(Run);

        myThread.Start();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(() => _listener.OnThreadCompleted());
    }
}
```

Comment: You could implement it directly into your `MonoBehaviour` class instead of using a Singleton pattern, though. If you additionally use a `ConcurrentQueue` you can also get rid of the `lock`.

Comment: @derHugo would you mind to answer a code example, please?

Answer (score 2):

This is just an example since you asked for it.

In general the `UnityMainThreadDispatcher` from your link is fine.

Anyway it simply works the queue in an `Update` method. I would instead of using this Singleton-Pattern solution simply do the same thing in the `MonoBehaviour` component you already have there (Singleton is in the most cases only a quick but dirty solution)

```
public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour, IMyComponentListener
{
    public GameObject cube;

    private MyComponent _myComponent;

    private ConcurrentQueue<Action> callbacks = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

    private void Start()
    {
        _myComponent = new MyComponent(this);
    }

    // Work the callbacks queue
    private void Update()
    {
        if(callbacks.Count == 0) return;

        while(callbacks.Count != 0)
        {
            Action a;
            if(!callbacks.TryDequeue(out a)) continue;

            a.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public void ThreadCompleted()
    {
        callbacks.Enqueue(OnThreadCompleted);
    }

    private void OnThreadCompleted()
    {
        cube.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 10f);
    }
}
```

And than you would call `enqueue` on that one instead e.g. like

```
((MyScript)_listener).ThreadCompleted();
```

Problem is maybe the typecast here .. or you could add the method to the interface.

---

In the case you have multiple listeners (as it seems due to the interface) I would also use your way maybe still without a Singleton but instead with proper references e.g. via the Inspector.

---

*Typed on my smartphone so no warranty but I hope I make my point clear*

Comment: You're welcome :) this setup basically worked for me for e.g. with a TCP client/server. Advantage is you can now disable that behaviour and the queue os not further executed.